# Python string and integer

Tags: python, math

I was doing some programming tasks in Python, but I have a problem. I have to enter `x` (it's length of list), then to enter integers and find the max of that list.

Input:

```
x = 3
43 75 84
```

Output: `84`

I tried this:

```
x = int(input())

n = input()
n.split()
n = list(map(int, n))
n.sort()

print(max(n))
```

Comment: Are you looking for a way to [convert a string to an int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)?

Comment: You may want to read the [ask] section of the FAQ.  Also, as a hint for this specific question, please check the [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#max) function in the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org).  The [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#max) are your best friend for this type of question.  Finally, you may want to remove some of the additional tags on your post.  This has nothing to do with [user-interface], [tkinter], or [wxpython].  It's just a straight out-of-the box Python question.

Comment: For example, I tried this: pastebin.com/6afkiKea

Comment: You should have posted that code in your question, not in a pastebin. Also post the error message you are getting. With that, we can surely help you. Without that, there are way too many possible answers for this question. You can still edit your question to include this information. Also, while you're at it, remove the user-interface, tkinter and wxpython tags please, they have absolutely nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need the number of integers but if you must enter and check it, the code could be like this.

```
number_of_integers = int(input('Number of integers: '))
data = input('Input values separated by spaces: ')
values = data.split()
if number_of_integers != len(values):
    print('Wrong number of values')
else:
    print(max(map(int, values)))
```

When you used `n.split()` you achieved nothing. Calling `split` will not turn `n` into a list. You have to use the return value.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use

```
sorted(your_list_of_numbers, reverse=True)
largest = your_list_of_numbers[0]
```